# Flatpak system operation ConfigureRemote not allowed for user

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, flatpak

I can't find an answer to what seems to be a simple question. I have a regular Chromebook. I'm new to Linux and just installed it today. I was following a guide that had me download a flatpack. I put in the command

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

and get

**Flatpak system operation ConfigureRemote is not allowed for the user**

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; what Ubuntu product & what release of that product are you using?  Ubuntu uses *deb* and *snap* packages by default; though *flatpak* and *appimage* can also be used, but aren't setup by default.

Comment: From a normal (non-root) prompt, adding flathub for all users on the system should require `sudo`. Adding flathub for only your user should be possible by adding `--user` to your command.

Answer (score 1):

Adding flathub for all users is not an allowed action. Try adding `sudo` to your command or only installing for one user.